# How to use custom UserDetailService in Spring OAuth2 Resource Server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot (2.3.4.RELEASE) to implement a webservice acting as a OAuth2 resource server. So far I'm able to secure all endpoints and ensure that a valid token is present. In the next step I want to use Spring Method Security. The third step would be to populate custom user details (via `UserDetailsService`).

### How to configure Spring Method Security properly?

I'm not able to enable Spring Method Security (correctly). I have entities saved in database and also set the permissions via MutableAclService. Creating new resource is no problem.

I get the following error on **reading** the entity

```
o.s.s.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator        : Checking permission 'OWNER' for object 'org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: io.mvc.webserver.repository.entity.ProjectEntity; Identifier: my-second-project]'
o.s.s.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator        : Returning false - no ACLs apply for this principal
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@120d62d, returned: -1
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@429b9eb9, returned: 0
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@65342bae, returned: 0
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Zugriff verweigert
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

I use the following Expression:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#projectKey, 'io.mvc.webserver.repository.entity.ProjectEntity', 'OWNER')")
ProjectEntity findByKey(String projectKey);
```

### How to provide Custom User Details Service?

As far as I understand Spring Security sets the SecurityContext accordingly to the authenticated user (by OAuth2 JWT). I want to set a custom user object (principal) based on the identified user from the token. But just providing a Bean of type `UserDetailsService` does not seem to work. My UserDetailsService is never invoked...

Security configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // TODO: Enable basic auth for actuator
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

ACL configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class AclConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);

        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator(PermissionFactory permissionFactory, AclService aclService) {
        AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator = new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService);
        permissionEvaluator.setPermissionFactory(permissionFactory);

        return permissionEvaluator;
    }

    @Bean
    public PermissionFactory permissionFactory() {
        return new DefaultPermissionFactory(MvcPermission.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public MutableAclService aclService(LookupStrategy lookupStrategy, AclCache aclCache, AclRepository aclRepository) {
        return new MongoDBMutableAclService(aclRepository, lookupStrategy, aclCache);
    }

    @Bean
    public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
        return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
        return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }

    @Bean
    public AclCache aclCache(PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy,
                             AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy,
                             EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean) {
        return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(
                ehCacheFactoryBean.getObject(),
                permissionGrantingStrategy,
                aclAuthorizationStrategy
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean) {
        EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
        return ehCacheFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cacheManagerFactory.setShared(true);
        return cacheManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate,
                                         AclCache aclCache,
                                         AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy) {
        return new BasicMongoLookupStrategy(
                mongoTemplate,
                aclCache,
                aclAuthorizationStrategy,
                new ConsoleAuditLogger()
        );
    }
}
```

dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Easy, spring native solution

If you want to use a custom user object, you need to implement and configer `Converter<Jwt,? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>`.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        MyConverter converter
    ) {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter);
        return http.build();
    }
```

If you have an UserDetailsService you should consider to make use of details instead of principal. Create a new JwtAuthenticationToken from the provided, parse in your authorities and use `jwt.setDetails(myUserDetails)`.
If you'd need to implement UserDetailsService yourself, it might be easier to just implement the converter and use your own variant of AbstractAuthenticationToken instead of replacement of the principal.

## Going forward / consideration

Jwt is a stateless authentication mechanism. Your converter will be used on every authenticated request. Your be careful about side effects like api or db lookup.
If you want to query additional user information from a database or api, consider to create a new token to encrypt everything that your application requires. You can also consider caching. Session cache can be a easy, worthy start here, since caching is mostly about performance boosts. It's a bit of a gray area with regards to statelessness.

## About the current accepted answer

There are various issues with the accepted answer. The biggest issue is, that it replaces the whole spring resource server jwt logic with a custom authentication filter. The answer even mentions, that you'd need to connect various logic like jwt parsing, that requires deeper understanding of either jwt or spring internals, so it only makes sense, if you need strong control over Authentication Header processing, but not if you just want to use your custom authentication class.

Answer (score 0):

In your ResourceServerConfig class you should override configureGlobal and authenticationManagerBean methods, as well as providing passwordEncoderBean in order to invoke your userDeatailsService:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

The variable userDetailsService in configureGlobal should hold a reference (through dependency injection @Autowird in your class) to your implementation of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService, in the implementation you should override the method loasUserByUsername to get the actual user in your database and pass the required values to UserDetails user, this user or Principal is what will be used in the authentication manager:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<UserFromDb> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (!user.isPresent()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
    }
    return new MyUser(user.get());
}
```

The class MyUser should implement org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails and pass the required values to MyUser as the example shows. How to pass the required values is up to you, here I passed the user from database and internally in the implementation I extracted whatever values are needed.

You should add the following line to the end of configure method

```
http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

authenticationTokenFilter is of a type that implements OncePerRequestFilter, you should override the method doFilterInternal:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    
    final String requestTokenHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");//sometime it's lowercase: authorization

    String username = getUserName(requestTokenHeader);
    String jwtToken = getJwtToken(requestTokenHeader);
    
    if (username != null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (isValidToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

Of course you should write the logic of getUserName, getJwtToken and isValidToken methods, which require understanding of JWT token and http headers...

Comment: My custom UserDetailsService is still not invoked. The SecurityContext contains an authentication object of type `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken`. The authentication object has a principal of type `class org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt`. I would like to use a custom principal here (via UserDetailsService).

Comment: in the configure method you should add http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); after the configuration. authenticationTokenFilter is a reference to some object implements OncePerRequestFilter, which in turn contains doFilterInternal method, you should override it and there you my set your principal SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(....)

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to extend OncePerRequestFilter ...

Comment: Why setting the authentication as usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken while we use JWT authentication initially ? Is it needed to set the UserDetailsService anyway ?