# Custom login REST endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to change default POST /login spring security endpoint for logging in to POST /api/users/login

I already tried doing that through

`formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/users/login")`

or

`formLogin().loginPage("/api/users/login")`

but it didn't work. How do i do that? I can't find tutorial describing it or stack overflow answer. I also tried reading Spring Security documentation but it didn't help too.

My security config looks like this:

```
    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //go from most restrictive url to least restrictive, from single urls to /**
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        //to allow h2 console page
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" are you getting error?

Comment: This might help: [spring-security-login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Comment: I mean that the endpoint for login didn't change. It still is under POST /login route instead of /api/users/login

Comment: The [spring-spring-security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) doesn't say anything about custom login route and also works with templates instead of REST endpoints.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to configure `fromLogin().loginPage()`? Given that you're passing a JWT, is this not a Resource Server? If so, then it should be configured with `httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer()`, which will authenticate the JWT and then allow it to access the resource. Why do you need a user login via `formLogin()`?

Comment: I meant to change REST endpoint for login, now form login. I finally found answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996726/changing-the-login-service-url-in-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

In the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class there is to configure methods that you should override like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
   http.csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                               unAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint)
       .and().sessionManagement()           
       .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
       .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
       .anyRequest()
       .authenticated();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter,
                          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity
            .ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/login")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and().ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").and().ignoring();
}
```

}

Please see in method:

```
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
```

the line:

```
webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/login")
```

This is where you put your custom authentication API endpoint!

And then you may proceed as I explained in the following question
[How to use custom UserDetailService in Spring OAuth2 Resource Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626686/how-to-use-custom-userdetailservice-in-spring-oauth2-resource-server/64627404#64627404)

Comment: Actually I am working with JWT tokens, not basic authentication but I just wanted to change login route from POST /login to something different. How this configuration achieves this?

Comment: @mixnix just omit .and().httpBasic(). But I assume you need additional implementation for JWT authentication and validation. Have you done all that?

Comment: Yes, everything works. Just on /login route and not on /api/users/login route. I added my security config to question